# How to ignore links that are located in parentheses?

Tags: python, selenium

I got a task to prove that most of wikipedia pages lead to a "Philosophy" page when you keep clicking the first link.

I created a code which finds the first link using xpath but the problem is I'm supposed to ignore links placed inside parentheses.

For example in text (links in bold):
Semiosis (from the **Greek**: σημείωσις, sēmeíōsis, a derivation of the verb σημειῶ, sēmeiô, "to mark") is any form of **activity**...

The first link in this div is "Greek" but that will get me in a loop so I want to filter that out and click the first link following the parentheses. In this case "activity".

Is there a way to ignore the links in parentheses?

```
start_page = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"

def click_link():
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mw-parser-output']/p/a")
    link.click()    

driver.get(start_page)

redirects = 0

title = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("title").text

while title != "Philosophy":
    click_link()
    redirects += 1
    title = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("title").text

print(redirects)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please add your code to your question

Comment: This is WAY more complicated than it seems at first glance.

Comment: You can't do this without parsing the HTML in the page which is going to be really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot more complicated than I initially thought it would be. The problem is that you can locate elements on the page using Selenium but you can't really see the textual context of that element, e.g. whether that link is inside `()`s. This is where it gets more difficult. If you look at everything as elements, you can't see context (you can't see what elements are inside other elements). If you look at everything as text (get `.text` from the parent), you can no longer see what is a link). The only way I could think of to do this is to:

1. Get the parent element that contains the first paragraph
2. Use `.get_attribute("innerHTML")` to get the HTML contained in that element
3. Search for a link that isn't inside `()`s with a regex

The problem is that once you find that, you have the string of the `A` tag and not an actual element that you can click on. With that text, you can do a couple things...

1. Get the text of the found link and find that on the page using a locator (so you can click on it) but that doesn't guarantee that it's the right link, e.g. imagine multiple links to "Greece" on the page, etc.
2. The other option is to look at the `href` of the found `A` tag and then reconstruct the URL that you can navigate to.

Here's some code to get you going in the right direction. You'll have to decide which path you want to take from here.

```
import re
...
start_page = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
driver.get(start_page)
first_para = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mw-content-text > div > p")
text = first_para.text
regex = "(<a .*?<\/a>)|\(.*?\)"
matches = re.findall(regex, text)
print(matches[1])
```

This will print `<a href="/wiki/Action_(philosophy)" title="Action (philosophy)">activity</a>` which is the first `A` tag that is not inside `()`s. From there, the approach is up to you. You can reconstruct the URL by parsing out the `href` attribute and appending it to the main URL like

```
new_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + href
```

or go a different direction. The choice is up to you and your requirements but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you, your solution seem to work. I have been given ad advice that the trick is in the right xpath search...

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code.Use following-Sibling to get the next child item.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver

def click_link():
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,5)

    element = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mw-parser-output']/p/a[1]/following-sibling::a")))
    element.click()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
title=driver.title


redirects=0
while title != "Action (philosophy) - Wikipedia":
    click_link()
    redirects += 1
    title =driver.title
    print(title)

print(redirects)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it's not the solution I'm looking for. The problem is the links in parentheses could be different (Greek, Latin, etc). Since I'm starting from a random page I need to figure out how to completely skip links placed inside the parentheses and click the first link outside of them.

Comment: @Chromec : I have updated the answer.Please check and let me know.

Comment: You haven't identified if the link is in parentheses.